# OpenGraph-App, app install before first app call

Tags: installation, facebook-opengraph

Since one week, we experiencing a new behavior in the install process of our application. Instead of first calling our app the installation seems to be invoked directly after requesting the app url.

A `die("hello world!")` on `line 1` in the **index.php** is shown after installation, not before. As we made a welcome-page which must be seen from users without installing our app we would like to know how to get back the old behavior?